# Can I access an object when being passed the name of the object as a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Say I'm doing this:

```
Foo = function () {};

o = Object.create(Foo, { p: {
  value: 42,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true }
});
o.prototype.bar = function () {console.log("hello");};

var x = "o";
window.o = o;
Object.defineProperty(window[x], "foo", { value: 123});
```

**Question**:
Is there any way to set a property on `o` without adding it to another object first (in this case window)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the other way is `eval`. However, adding the object as a property to an object like you have is indeed the way to go, limiting ("whitelisting") the possible names explicitly. Of course you could also use `if-else` or `switch`, but these are tedious to write.

Comment: Good idea with evil `eval`

Comment: Or bad idea… Depending on what you are using it for.

Comment: in my case bad idea... still - did not think about it.